# Подсчет результатов отбора в массиве PHP

Tags: php

Уважаемые программисты, прошу помочь новичку.

В массиве указал людей кто выше Иры в её классе, ее рост 169, выбрал этих людей и вывел на экран, а теперь ломаю голову как их подсчитать и отобразить сумму на мониторе? Помогите...

пример кода:

```
   <?php
$Ira = 169;

$class = array (
'anton' => 172,
'igor' => 173,
'dasha' => 188,
'dima' => 160
);

foreach ($class as $name => $hai) {
if (in_array($hai>169, $class)) {
echo $name,'<br/>';
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать проще:

Использовать [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php), чтоб отсортировать людей по заданному критерию. А далее просто взять `count` получившегося массива

```
// input data

$Ira = 169;

$class = array (
'anton' => 172,
'igor' => 173,
'dasha' => 188,
'dima' => 160
);

// logic
$people = array_filter($class, function($class) use ($Ira) {    
    return $class > $Ira;
});

echo count($people); // выведет 3
```

Answer (score 1):

В условии нужно суммировать, а после цикла вывести

```
$class = array (
'anton' => 172,
'igor' => 173,
'dasha' => 188,
'dima' => 160
);

$sum = 0;
foreach ($class as $name => $hai) {
if (in_array($hai>169, $class)) {
echo $name,'<br/>';
$sum++;
}
}
echo $sum;
```

Comment: Вроде не сумма роста имеется ввиду

Comment: простите, количество человек кто выше имел ввиду...

Comment: @KBMira, хорошо, поправил

Comment: @Komdosh Спасибо, за ответ, а не могли бы объяснить $__++ в цикле всегда сумму дает?

Comment: Нет, $sum это обычная переменная, перед циклом я задал ей значение 0, а потом на каждом шаге цикла, когда условие срабатывало увеличивал $sum на один. $sum++ это короткий аналог $sum=$sum+1;

Comment: все понял. спасибо, да я про ++ имел ввиду